# Creating an associative array and then inserting values to table

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I have a page with a list of different images that are displayed in a specific order depending on their value in the column "order" in a MySQL table. $a is the image id and $b is the value of the "order" column.

I want to be able to change the order in which the images are displayed by changing their values in the "order" column. Therefore, I want to loop through the list of images, display them in a form with a text box right next to the image with their current "order" values stored in the database. 
The problem is that I do not know how to collect the information from the form and use it to update the information in the database. Since I am just a newbie at programming I do not know if I need an associative array $a => $b and then somehow use that in a query to insert the value of $b where the image id is equal to $a. I have no idea how to do that.
I checked this answer: [Manually creating an associative array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4337540/manually-creating-an-associative-array), but I wasn't able to make anything work.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Let's say your form looks something like this:

```
<form>
    <input type="text" name="img001" value="1" />
    <input type="text" name="img002" value="2" />
    <input type="text" name="img003" value="3" />
</form>
```

The PHP that processes the form data would look like this:

```
<?php
// always sanitize your input data
function onlyInteger($input){
    return (int) $input;
};
$data = array_map("onlyInteger",$_POST);

// build up the SQL
$sql_statements = array();
foreach ($data as $imgname => $sortvalue) {
    $sql_statements[] = "UPDATE ImagesTable SET order = $sortvalue WHERE imgname = '$imgname'"
}

// execute the SQL
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "world");
$result = $mysqli->query( implode('; ',$sql_statements) );
?>
```